# MSVC - Executable builds correctly but DLL doesn't, missing symbols and conflicting dependencies - SSCCE/Repro

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, linker, msvcrt

I have a working executable here and I'm trying to build a DLL from the same code, but I'm having some strange errors and managed to pinpoint the culprits after a lot of trial an error, I decided to ask for help because I'm really stuck now. I'm linking both SDL2 and Cimgui (Dear Imgui C Wrapper) statically in my code, the executable works perfectly fine:

```c
#include "imgui/imgui.h"
#include "cimgui.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "cimgui.lib")

#include "SDL.h"
#undef main
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL2-staticd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "imm32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "version.lib")

void main()
{
    SDL_Init(0);
    igCreateContext(0);
    printf("OK");
}
```

So now I switch the project to *DLL* (I disabled that `/IMPLIB` option to make sure the **only difference** in the link command is the `/DLL` and the extension). When I try to build I get errors regarding `cimgui.lib` like:

```
cimgui.lib(imgui_draw.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcmp
cimgui.lib(imgui_widgets.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memcpy
cimgui.lib(imgui.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol memset
```

Apparently the Visual C runtime isn't being linked anymore, I don't really understand why, I could just add it immediately but let's step back and remove Cimgui from the code:

```c
#include "SDL.h"
#undef main
#pragma comment(lib, "SDL2-staticd.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "imm32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "version.lib")

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void main()
{
    SDL_Init(0);
}
```

I get 13 errors similar to this:

```
MSVCRTD.lib(_init_.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _CrtDbgReport referenced in function _CRT_RTC_INIT
```

So I manually include the libs that contain the missing symbols: `ucrtd.lib`, `vcruntimed.lib`, and then the DLL builds fine.

Now I try to add Cimgui again, but it fails to build with errors like these:

```
MSVCRTD.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __vcrt_initialize referenced in function __scrt_initialize_crt
MSVCRTD.lib(utility.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __acrt_initialize referenced in function __scrt_initialize_crt
```

the `__vcrt` definitions are in `libvcruntimed.lib`, but the `__acrt` definitions are in `libucrtd.lib`, which conflicts with `ucrtd.lib`, and even if I remove `ucrtd.lib` altogether and try to link just `libucrtd.lib`, I get errors like:

```
ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll) : error LNK2005: malloc already defined in libucrtd.lib(malloc.obj)
```

Which I don't know how to interpret because I'm not linking `ucrtd.lib`.

I don't really understand why building a DLL isn't just like building an Executable especially because the EXE binary is very similar to the DLL and I could even use it to interop as a DLL but that doesn't feel right. I'm sure there's a way to build this and I just don't know how.

For completeness (and just in case), here are the linker commands for the EXE and DLL:

```
/OUT:"C:\Projects\BuildTest\x64\Debug\Build.dll" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Projects\BuildTest\x64\Debug\Build.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /DLL /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Projects\BuildTest\x64\Debug\Build.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\Build.dll.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Projects\cimgui_build\Debug" /LIBPATH:"C:\Projects\SDL2-2.0.8\build\Debug" /TLBID:1 
/OUT:"C:\Projects\BuildTest\x64\Debug\Build.exe" /MANIFEST /NXCOMPAT /PDB:"C:\Projects\BuildTest\x64\Debug\Build.pdb" /DYNAMICBASE "kernel32.lib" "user32.lib" "gdi32.lib" "winspool.lib" "comdlg32.lib" "advapi32.lib" "shell32.lib" "ole32.lib" "oleaut32.lib" "uuid.lib" "odbc32.lib" "odbccp32.lib" /DEBUG /MACHINE:X64 /INCREMENTAL /PGD:"C:\Projects\BuildTest\x64\Debug\Build.pgd" /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE /MANIFESTUAC:"level='asInvoker' uiAccess='false'" /ManifestFile:"x64\Debug\Build.exe.intermediate.manifest" /ERRORREPORT:PROMPT /NOLOGO /LIBPATH:"C:\Projects\cimgui_build\Debug" /LIBPATH:"C:\Projects\SDL2-2.0.8\build\Debug" /TLBID:1
```

EDIT:

I made a "Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example" (Self-contained - dependencies included, relative paths, VS2017 project, should compile directly provided you have Windows SDK) and published online here:

https://bitbucket.org/AlanGameDev/buildmvce_so/downloads/

(you can download and extract or clone if you prefer)

Comment: What is your `/ENTRY` setting? Did you rebuild or at least clean then build after modifying your project? Actually, this kind of problem requires an [MCVE] and for that you need to post your makefile or project file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @jwdonahue I made a MCVE and published online here: https://bitbucket.org/AlanGameDev/buildmvce_so/downloads/ (you can either download or clone directly if you prefer)

Comment: @KenWhite I'm afraid this isn't a duplicate of that since it's probably related to conflicting MSVCRT dependencies I guess... I don't know exactly what's the problem, but it's not simply missing symbols, as I said I know where are the symbols but can't link the files, and also I would like to know why building an EXE is so different than a DLL.

Comment: @jwdonahue I forgot to say that yes I always rebuild the whole shebang :)

Comment: @KenWhite that was just an intermediary step to explain what I've tried, as I said the definitions for the LNK2019 errors are in the libvcruntimed.lib and libucrtd.lib libraries, so that's not what's stopping me

Comment: `#pragma comment(lib, ...` is a bad habit IMHO. It won't work with other tool chains. Better to specify libraries to link in your build system.

Comment: @JesperJuhl yes, I'm just using that because the repro is for MSVC and that way it's much easier imho to add/remove libs, but thanks for the heads up ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the linker flag /VERBOSE to both exe/dll builds and diff the results, you'd get a clue as to what's going on.

In the exe build you'd see

```
1>      Found mainCRTStartup
1>        Loaded MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj)
...

1>      Found __xi_a
1>        Referenced in MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj)
1>        Loaded MSVCRTD.lib(initializers.obj)
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:kernel32.lib
1> Processed /DISALLOWLIB:msvcrt.lib
1> Processed /DISALLOWLIB:libcmt.lib
1> Processed /DISALLOWLIB:libcmtd.lib
1> Processed /DISALLOWLIB:vcruntime.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:vcruntimed.lib
1> Processed /DISALLOWLIB:libvcruntime.lib
1> Processed /DISALLOWLIB:libvcruntimed.lib
1> Processed /DISALLOWLIB:ucrt.lib
1>Processed /DEFAULTLIB:ucrtd.lib
1> Processed /DISALLOWLIB:libucrt.lib
1> Processed /DISALLOWLIB:libucrtd.lib
```

**none of which** appear in the dll build.  In the dll build you'd see only -

```
1>      Found _DllMainCRTStartup
1>        Loaded SDL2-staticd.lib(SDL.obj)
```

Which is very weird. It seems SDL2 includes its own implementation of the entry point _DllMainCRTStartup, and since the linker takes it from there and not the crt lib - it misses a whole lot of useful /DEFAULTLIB pragmas.

Googling around it seems the _dllMainCRTStartup is included within SDL [to satisfy some Watcom needs](http://lists.libsdl.org/pipermail/commits-libsdl.org/2018-February/002618.html), and it was already suspected to cause trouble in MSVC.

If you build SDL from sources you should probably just comment out the _dllMainCRTStartup implementation and (hopefully) build successfully.

Comment: Thanks. It is indeed the implementations in SDL that were causing the problem. There's a CMake flag for that btw. I still don't quite understand why that only happens when you build the DLL though. Do DLLs link all dependencies statically or something like that?

Comment: The default entry point *for an dll* is _dllMainCRTStartup, so it is required only for dll linkage. In regular builds the linker finds this entry point somewhere in MSVCRTD.lib (probably in dll_main.obj or similar), and i'm guessing this obj uses symbols that require initializers.obj. initializers.obj includes a bunch of linker directives like '/DEFAULTLIB:vcruntimed.lib' (probably as pragmas in the source), which cause the rest of the link to succeed.  When you link agains SDL this entire train is taken off track - this is simply an SDL bug when building a dll on MSVC.

Comment: BTW kudos for the small repro. It would have been impossible to investigate otherwise

Comment: Thank you for your valuable help @OfekShilon. It's really appreciated.